# Problem when playing music with Arduino

Tags: arduino, audio, music

I am using an Arduino Nano in combination with a SD card to play some music. I have loaded some .wav files on my SD card, the card initializes, everything runs correctly, but on my output pin for my music I get an unstable square wave signal all the time.

I have tried to change the CS pin to pin 4 and 10 (only pin 4 works), I have tried different .wav files and a bunch of code and all of my libraries are installed. What can I do?

[image]

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <TMRpcm.h>

TMRpcm audio;

void setup() {
  audio.speakerPin = 9;

  //starting up SD
  Serial.begin(9600);
  if (!SD.begin(4)) {
    Serial.println("Initialization failed");
    while (true) {
    }
  }
  Serial.println("Initialization complete");

  audio.setVolume(3);
  audio.play("SSTC.wav");
}

void loop() {
}
```

Comment: Is the output meant to be a PWM modulated square wave, or is does the arduino have a DAC?

Comment: It is meant to be PWM. But the signal I get out is no music whatsoever. Just weird signals.

Comment: One more thing, If I give it different songs, It gives me different types of buzzes.....so....something is working...

Comment: What bandwidth can TMRpcm handle? I doubt it has remotely the bandwidth for ordinary audio WAV files, especially on an Arduino Nano.

Comment: Can you open and play the file in audio player/editor? What format it is? Can the Arduino library play that format? Have you tried to play some simpler test files, like a -3dB 440 Hz sine wave stored as 8-bit unsigned PCM at 8 kHz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is (probably) working as intended. From the TMRpcm library's Wiki:

> If using an amplifier, consider that the output is a choppy digital PWM signal, not a smooth analog signal.

This could be what you are seeing: the output is PWM, not analog. The PWM signal you get is supposed to be low-pass filtered by either a filter or the characteristics of the speaker you use.

If you want analog output, you need to pass the PWM through a low-pass filter, or use a microcontroller with a DAC, or use an external DAC (and a different library for the last two options).

Another possible problem is the performance of the Arduino Nano with .wav files with a high sample rate and bit depth; the library's Wiki says:

> Main formats: WAV files, 8-bit, 8-32khz Sample Rate, mono.

It could be your .wav file doesn't comply with that.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response! There is only one problem though. The .wav file I gave it has PWM music on it (the original PWM signal vs the output Arduino PWM signal are very different). But if I amplify the signal coming out of the Arduino, it resembles NOTHING of the original. Just some weird buzzes.

Comment: @GeorgeChita: I don't know if a .wav file can contain PWM data, but it is at least very unusual; most .wav files contain [LPCM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) data. Are you sure your .wav file contains PWM data?

Comment: Yes, I am sure, it is PWM, though not with constant amplitude.

Comment: Thank you very much. The file wasn't compatible. It finally worked. Thank you again!

Comment: @GeorgeChita: you may want to accept the answer (if you accept the answer), so the question doesn't stay open.

Comment: Ohhh, sorry, I'm new to the site. I will accept it ofcourse! The circuit finally worked! Thank you again!